# Stuck with a simple bibtex

Tags: bibtex

My file test2.tex

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
\section{Hello}
Testing Bibs from Jabref
\cite{einstein}

\bibliography{mybib}
\bibliographystyle{plain}


\end{document}
```

and my mybib.bib file

```
@article{einstein,
    author =       "Albert Einstein",
    title =        "{Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K{\"o}rper}. ({German})
        [{On} the electrodynamics of moving bodies]",
    journal =      "Annalen der Physik",
    volume =       "322",
    number =       "10",
    pages =        "891--921",
    year =         "1905",
    DOI =          "http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/andp.19053221004"
}
```

Compile using pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode -synctex=1 test2.tex

I always get an error : 
Citation einstein is undefined and No file test2.bbl

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you run `pdflatex test2.tex`, `bibtex test2`, `pdflatex test2.tex`,`pdflatex test2.tex`?

Comment: Works flawless here. Maybe delete all `.bbl` and `.aux` files . . .

Comment: Did you read [Question mark instead of citation number](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852)?

Comment: @DG does it work without running the command bibtex test2 at your end also? Because thats what I was missing. I thought that that command would be automatically invoked by the IDE ( Latexilla ) I am using. Unfortunately, that was not the case and had to explicitly invoke the bibtex command on the CLI.

Comment: I used `latexmk`, which is also the `LaTeXila` default...